# Was bedeutet "w.o. geben"?

Tags: phrase

Es ist eine Art *"ich geb' auf"* soweit ich verstanden habe.

- Was wird damit genau gemeint?
- Wie schreibt man es?
- Ist es eine Abkürzung und wenn ja, wofür?

Answer (score 6):

Erster Link bei Google wenn man "w.o. geben" eingibt:

Wikipedia zu [Walkover](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkover):

> Walkover, abgekürzt w. o. (engl. auch walk-over oder w/o; dt. "Spaziergang, leichtes Spiel"), ist eine Situation, wenn ein Spieler nicht zum Spiel antritt und dadurch das Spiel für ihn als verloren gewertet wird. Gelegentlich wird er darüber hinaus bei einer Aufgabe oder Disqualifikation eines Spielers im Verlauf des Spiels verwendet.
>
> Der Ausdruck stammt ursprünglich aus dem Pferderennsport. Nach Aufgabe aller Gegner musste der letzte verbleibende Teilnehmer bloß noch die Ziellinie überschreiten ("walk over the line"), um den Sieg zu beanspruchen, konnte das Rennen also gleichsam "im Spaziergang" beenden.
>
> **Wer dem Gegner ein Walkover ermöglicht, "hat w. o. gegeben"**.